# SSRS report - Export to Excel - not showing the footer information

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS 2012. When I export the report into PDF I am getting a correct format same as in my report preview. But when I export the report in to Excel all details are shown except footer image.
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

The footer information is specific to the page and since once you export to Excel, you no longer have the pagination that you normally have, the footer is no longer a valid part of the report.  The reason they don't include the footer is that when you export to Excel you are exporting a single continuous report without page breaks. Including the page footer information would insert the footers into the data giving you a real mess.  Take a simple footer that displays the ReportName, Page # of #s and DataDate.  Displaying this footer would mean that at every page break this information would be inserted into your spreadsheet.  In most cases this not an acceptable scenario.  It sounds like what you're looking for is a "Report Footer", which for some reason MS chose not to include in SSRS. What you could try is putting the footer image into the footer of your tablix and using something long the lines of

```
=iif(Globals!PageNumber=Globals!TotalPages,true,false)
```

to control displaying it.